# Installing php7.0 extensions

Tags: php, ubuntu

In ubuntu 16.04 I've already checked php 7.0 version has installed.

However, I found that I have missed below extensions.

```
with-openssl
with-libxml-dir
with-mcrypt
enable-sockets
```

Is there any waty to install these php extensions easily in ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
```

how to install [sockets.installation](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get install -y  php7.0-mcrypt
```

Installing [PHP 5.6](http://webtatic.com/packages/php56/) here is a good guide to install all of the extensions and other details but it's for Redhat and CentOS, the concept is pretty same for all though.